# Curl converts '@sha256' into '&#64;sha256'

Tags: curl, html-entities

I am trying to curl some text displayed on a webpage which include:

```
repo@sha256
```

When I run `curl -s https://website` the corresponding output is:

```
repo&#64;sha256
```

Why is this, and is there a cleaner way to fix this other than editing the resulting output with something like sed or awk?

Comment: That's a correct means for encoding a `@` in HTML or XML. Without knowing what format the page you're retrieving there's only so much we can say, other than "use a parser that knows the format of the page you're retrieving".

Comment: This looks like the website is using the HTML entity `&64;` for the `@` character - I'm pretty sure curl does not touch the content it's downloading.

Comment: Anyhow -- the _clean_ approach involves selecting an appropriate tool for the job at hand. This might be using something like `xmllint` if you're extracting data from an XML document, or a Python library like `lxml.html` or ElementTree. Since we don't know the document format (much less the individual page!) you're trying to parse, there's not enough information given to allow a firm recommendation (if the use case would benefit from something like XPath-based extraction, that kind of detail would greatly influence which tools are right for the job).

Comment: It is not a publicly available page. How would I know the document type? The page just displays the text as I would expect with the '@', but in the page source I see the text is preceded by "<td class='lines'><pre><code>#" and then uses the '&#64;'

Answer (score 6):

curl does **not** convert that. It is exactly the other way around: curl *does not* convert it, it delivers the exact bytes the server provides.

You probably saw the '@' symbol in a browser that displays HTML and in HTML `&#64;` is displayed as `@`.